# AS 2 Scroll to the top with delay

Tags: flash, scroll, actionscript-2, delay

I have a scroller and a problem:

```
function scrolling(){
_root.onEnterFrame = function() {

    function fun()      {
        moz = -94;
    }

    setTimeout(fun,5000);

    container_mc._y = (moz);

    if (container_mc._y > mask_mc._y)       {
        container_mc._y = mask_mc._y;
    }

    if (container_mc._y < (mask_mc._y - (container_mc._height - mask_mc._height)))      {
        container_mc._y = mask_mc._y - (container_mc._height - mask_mc._height - 1782);
    }

};
```

}

I would like to the content move to top, but I don't know how to. And I would like to delay. Most important think the motion is not continuous! The unit is roughly 94px. I need to some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you're aware of the fact that you're missing one ending } bracket on the end, right?

i don't know what exactly do you mean by "move content to top" but to make the movement smooth instead of `container_mc._y = (moz);` do this:

```
container_mc._y+=(moz-container_mc._y)/5; //you may modify the 5 to adjust the speed
```

Comment: Thanks for asking

The container_mc contain picrtures. Pictures are moving, but this is wrong. I would like to the pictures move to step by step delayed. 
Now the first picture move up and my script is the end. I would like to move the second picture and the third picture etc.

Comment: honestly, i don't understand you very much. perhaps you could provide us with pictures with arrows in it/ etc?